# How to display the charts row-wise instead of column wise

Tags: r, ggplot2

`marrangeGrob` apparently displays the charts by column first. How to arrange these charts row-wise instead?

```
library(gridExtra)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
dat <- c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1)
time <- 1:10
data <- tibble(dat, time)
p1 <- ggplot(data, aes(x= time, y=dat)) +
  geom_point(color="orange")
p2 <- ggplot(data, aes(x= time, y=dat)) +
  geom_point(color="blue")
clist <- list(p1,p2)
marrangeGrob(clist, nrow=2, ncol=2, as.table=F )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `layout_matrix` argument you could specify to add the plots by row (`byrow=TRUE`):

```r
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)
dat <- c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1)
time <- 1:10
data <- data.frame(dat, time)
p1 <- ggplot(data, aes(x= time, y=dat)) +
  geom_point(color="orange")
p2 <- ggplot(data, aes(x= time, y=dat)) +
  geom_point(color="blue")
clist <- list(p1,p2)

marrangeGrob(clist, nrow=2, ncol=2, 
             layout_matrix = matrix(seq_len(4), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE))
```

[image]